# Cell Row Height based on Image size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I'm using an API and **need to adjust the `UITableViewCell` height based on the Image Height.**

My `if` statement needs to be:

- if there is no image then to set the height to 140, else...
- if thereis an image then set the height to 106 + imageHeight

I can't seem to get this working, any ideas?

Will post any extra code as needed, thanks!

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
Feed *feedLocal = [headlinesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([feedLocal.images count] == 0) {
        return 140;
    }
else {
        Images *image = [feedLocal.images objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *imageHeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", image.height];
        return 106 + imageHeight;
    }
```

I'm getting an error on `return 106 + imageHeight;` that says "Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'NSString' which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform", and the app crashes when it hits that spot.

EDIT: Content of array (JSON from API)

```
"feed": [{
        "headline": "xxx",
        "lastModified": "xxxx",
        "images": [{
            "height": 300,
            "alt": "xxx",
            "width": 300,
            "name": "xxx",
            "caption": "xxx",
            "url": "http://xxx.jpg"
        }],
```

Images.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *height;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *width;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *caption;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *url;

+ (RKObjectMapping *) mapping;
```

Images.m

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class] usingBlock:^(RKObjectMapping *mapping) {
        [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
        @"height", @"height",
         @"width", @"width",
         @"caption", @"caption",
         @"url", @"url",
         nil];
    }];

    return objectMapping;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add a string to a number? Also what is image.height? UIImage doesn't have a height property.

Comment: @rdelmar thanks for the response!  `image.height` is supposed to be getting the height from the `Feed` JSON response.  I'm newer to this so I'm not sure if that answered your question, I'm not doing something right but I'm not aware of what it is.

Comment: I'm sure I need to add a number to 106, so is there a way I can convert the `imageHeight` into a number?  Or am I thinking about that the wrong way?

Comment: I updated the question with more info if you needed it-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempt to return the addition of a number with a string. Instead use:

```
    Images *image = [feedLocal.images objectAtIndex:0];
    CGFloat imageHeight = image.size.height;
    return 106 + imageHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually attempted to do this too, but was getting on error on the second line "Property `size` not found on object type of 'Images'.  I'm not quite sure why that is though?

Comment: Have your Images class the property size? feedLocal.images contain images? Is Images a subclass of UIImage class?

Comment: feedLocal.images is an array, in which there are height and width.  Is that what you're asking about?  Thanks

Comment: Could you put an example of the content of the array?

Comment: Added the array and the Images.h+.m

Comment: You have define heigth as NSNumber. Try to use [imageHeight floatValue].

Comment: Ok, where would I put the `[imageHeight floatValue]` in your suggested answer?  Does that go in `return 106 + [imageHeight floatValue]`?

Comment: In return 106 + [imageHeight floatValue];

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this code?

```
else {

  Images *image = [feedLocal.images objectAtIndex:0];
  return 106+image.size.height;

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I have tried that actually, and it gives me the error that property `size` is not found on the object of type `Images`

Comment: Added the array and Images class above